# How do I add specific files to .gitignore (Unity)

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitlab

I would like to know how to add some things to the .gitignore file in my Unity project. I want to ignore the buildsettings and the playersettings but I have no idea how to do this.

On Google I only see how to temporarely do this. I just want to ignore them forever in the gitignore.

How do I do this if I would type in the .gitignore file?

Further information: Using Gitbash for pushing and pulling.

Comment: open the file in a texteditor, add the file path ... save done ... why would you like to ignore those settings? The paths you are looking for are `\ProjectSettings\EditorBuildSettings.asset` and `\ProjectSettings\ProjectSettings.asset`

Answer (score 0):

For general purpose there're a lot templates you may have interest to look into: https://github.com/github/gitignore

And for Unity I often use this template: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

---

Example, write relative path to ignore specific files:

```
unity_project/
  tmp.txt      <- ignore
  Assets/
```

Have this line in gitignore is enough:

```
tmp.txt
```

Or ignore all *.txt in all directories under `unity_project`:

```
*.txt
```

---

Specifically the files you want to ignore are (thanks @derHugo):

```
ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset
ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset
```

Comment: The paths you are looking for are `\ProjectSettings\EditorBuildSettings.asset` and `\ProjectSettings\ProjectSettings.asset`

Comment: @derHugo ? I think you commented under wrong place.

Comment: no .. OP asked `I want to ignore the buildsettings and the playersettings` so I'm helping you to write a complete answer ;)

Comment: no they are **not** because usually you do **never** want to ignore any files from `Assets` and `ProjectSettings`

Comment: @derHugo oh ok. I see it.